# Non-Highcharts library for plotting activity time (like basic gantt chart)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, charts

I would like to find a library that can plot bars to show times when activities have happened and for how long, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/ (or at least reasonably similar).

Since it's for something that's not going to make money I rather not pay for High Charts. More importantly I'd eventually like to open source it and rather not have problems with licencing or annoying people by explaining they possibly need to buy High Charts.

So what would be the best solution for creating similar charts without highcharts?